# Best method for checking field present only in child class?

Tags: haxe

I'm writing a comparison function and I need to check the value of class-specific fields when those fields are present in both objects.  Naturally, Haxe's compile-time checks throw an error as the interface doesn't include the field.

I've tried wrapping the code that checks for the field (`Std.is(record, MX)` and `Reflect.hasField(record,'prio')`) as well as a safe cast:

```
        try {
            cast(record, MX);
            return compareNumber(this.prio, record.prio);
        } catch(error:Dynamic) {
            //do nothing because we figured out type earlier in the code.
        }
```

The compiler doesn't seem to notice.  The best workaround I've come up with is to pass it into a convenience function that has a Dynamic type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way would be to use [`Std.instance`](http://api.haxe.org/Std.html#instance), which calls `Std.is` and a `cast`:

```
var result = super.compare(record);
var sub = Std.instance(record, MX);  // returns either record:MX or null
if (result == 0 && sub != null)
    result = compareNumber(this.prio, sub.prio);
return result;
```

Since `Std.instance` first checks if the cast is possible, it can then use a faster unsafe cast.  The implementation is easy to follow: [JS](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/8970fea667f963a31efd9278104845b20c85b66b/std/js/_std/Std.hx#L32), [C++](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/b84884d7d8c1abad7ad85a38c38bb8298f52d485/std/cpp/_std/Std.hx#L28).

---

A note pertaining the example on your question: the reason why it didn't work is that `cast(record, MX)` by itself does not change the type following that declaration (they might change the inferred type of `record` if it's a monomorph, but then I don't think safe casts are allowed in this case).  Casts are expressions, just like everything else in Haxe, and for them to be useful, you need to assign their result to some variable (like you did in your answer, but explicitly typing the variable is optional).

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the variable to a more strictly typed version of itself seems to have fixed the problem:

```
public function compare(record:InterfaceName):Int{

    var result = super.compare(record);  //checks of all common fields which also happens to determine type

    if(result == 0){
        try{
            var record:MX = cast(record, MX);
            return compareNumber(this.prio, record.prio);
        } catch(error:Dynamic){
            //do nothing
        }
    }


    return result;
}
```

However, the documentation on [safe cast](http://haxe.org/manual/expression-cast-safe.html) and [type check](http://haxe.org/manual/expression-type-check.html) doesn't include this step (although the type-check entry doesn't really have an example) and I suspect there is a better solution.